# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER' when creating stored procedure which creating trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My goal is to create a stored procedure which creates a trigger on defined table to track changes from it to `<table_name>_versions` table.

I'm doing it with dynamic SQL like so:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_create_track_versions_trigger
    @tableName VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX);

    -- Get column names list with brackets 
    SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), ',')
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = @tableName;

    -- Create dynamic sql with params
    SET @sql = N'
    CREATE TRIGGER [' + @tableName + '_TrackVersionsTrigger]
    ON [' + @tableName + ']
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert data from <tableName> into <tableName>_versions table
        INSERT INTO [' + @tableName + '_versions] (' + @columns + ', version_id, version_timestamp)
        SELECT ' + @columns + ',
               NEWID()   AS version_id,
               GETDATE() AS version_timestamp
        FROM inserted;
    END';

    -- Execute dynamic sql
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@tableName VARCHAR(256)', @tableName = @tableName;
END;
```

Procedure created successfully, but on execution

```
EXEC sp_create_track_versions_trigger @tableName = 'test_table'
```

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'

What did I miss?

Comment: `PRINT` the statement(s) you are generated and debug those, then propagate the solution.

Comment: Also syntax like `'[' + SomeExpression + ']'` isn't injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME` to properly quote your injected values. `sysname` is also the correct data type for an object name (a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`). You should also really be defining the schema in your query too.

Comment: Though, I do wonder, why not just use a temporal table?

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Note that `QuoteName` is appropriate on most object names, e.g. when assembling the list of column names. All you need is one odd column, e.g. `Shoe Size`, to make a mess of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the error is because `CREATE TRIGGER` needs to be the *only* statement in the batch. The first statement in your dynamic batch, however, is `DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(256);` as you are passing *parameters*. Why do you need to pass the value of `@tableName` when it isn't used in the dynamic batch? It's the cause for the error, and likely should be removed.

The correct code, with some injection and parameter fixing (among other things), should likely be something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.create_track_versions_trigger --sp_ prefix removed, see comments
    @schemaName sysname = N'dbo', --Assumed default
    @tableName sysname --Corrected datatype
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @columns nvarchar(MAX); --Corrected datatype

    -- Get column names list with brackets 
    SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), N',')
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@schemaName),N'.',QUOTENAME(@tableName))); --Make SARGable

    -- Create dynamic sql with params
    DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    --Going to improve the formatting a little here
    SET @sql = N'CREATE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName + N'_TrackVersionsTrigger') + @CRLF +
               N'ON ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + @CRLF +
               N'AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS' + @CRLF +
               N'BEGIN' + @CRLF +
               N'    SET NOCOUNT ON;' + @CRLF +
               N'' + @CRLF +
               N'    -- Insert data from <tableName> into <tableName>_versions table' + @CRLF +
               N'    INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName + N'_versions') + N' (' + @columns + ', version_id, version_timestamp)' + @CRLF +
               N'    SELECT ' + @columns + ',' + @CRLF +
               N'           NEWID()   AS version_id,' + @CRLF +
               N'           GETDATE() AS version_timestamp' + @CRLF +
               N'    FROM inserted;' + @CRLF +
               N'END';

    -- Execute dynamic sql
    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
GO
```

Though, as I mentioned in the comments, I would suggest that instead of "reinventing the wheel" you actually just use a temporal table; then that handles the whole thing automatically.

Comment: Nice! Works fine after one modification for my case: select all column names to @columns except id as it is auto generated primary key. Like that: ```SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), N',')
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(@schemaName),N'.',QUOTENAME(@tableName))) AND name <> 'id';```

Comment: That seems like one of the most important columns, @TropinAlexey ... If you don't store the PK, you have **no idea** what row was `INSERT`ed/`UPDATE`d. That column *definitely* should be included.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I must modify my _versions table schema with column ```version_id``` as primary key instead